# Measure the length of the platform in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, platformer

I created a platform in Unity. It consists of an empty parent object and child objects. Child object have attached components: `Sprite renderer` and `Edge collider 2D`.

How could I get the length and height of such a platform? By the length and height in the case I mean the respective measures in x and y axis.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `width` scale value of the platform. This should return the 'length value' of it.

So, if you had a platform at around `position 0, 0, 0` and a scale at around `scale 32, 8, 0`, then you have the length of it sideways. You can do the same thing, only with the `height` value to get the length in that dimension.

**EDIT**

In case anyone, or the user that asked this question, finds this answer, and does not want to look in the comments, I thought I should edit and add this in.

When I said 'scale values,' i meant the scale of the Transform. So, use the transform scale values when reading my answer.

Comment: I do not get a point, elaborate it please. What scale are you talking about? As you can tell from the screenshot the scale is `1` for every dimension.

Comment: In the transform component of the game object in question, look for the `position` and `scale` vectors; they should have three values, one by one, next to each other. Those are the are the values I'm talking about.

Comment: But the transform scale is set to one on all three components as you can tell from the `Inspector` view on the screenshot, while the width of the platform is definitely not one.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then you could use the SpriteRenderer's bounds. `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x` for the length in the x axis, and `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.y` for the length in the y.axis.